# Traffic value of a keyword

Tags: seo, search-engines, keywords, tools

Does anyone know what kind of tools or **tests I can run to find the traffic value of a keyword**?

I have done a search here before and someone's asked a similar question which was helpful but what I need to find out is what the Traffic Value, not the monetary value of a keyword is please?

Comment: Has your question been answered Sixfoot or do you need some more answers?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Keyword Tool External](https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal). It provides both Traffic Estimate and CPC values optionally.

Comment: Hi JP. Can you tell me what a CPC value is please?

Comment: CPC is for cost per click. Google Keyword tool will give you nice statistics like CPC, competition, monthly trends, global/local (countrywise) searches for the word/phrase, etc.

Comment: Click "Columns" to see the CPC option.  Google hides it.

Answer (score 0):

Google external tool and digital traffic tool they both are great and accurate tool .

Answer (score 0):

While not a tool, one thing I would say is that the value of a keyword is directly related to your ability capitalize on in.

[JP19](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8159/seo-keyword-value/8163#8163)'s reference to [Google Keyword Tool External](https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal) is a super start, beyond that there hundreds if not thousands of such tools; such as: [KeywordSpy](http://www.keywordspy.com/), [Wordtracker](https://freekeywords.wordtracker.com/), etc.